# Create registry key programmatically

Tags: c#, registrykey

I'm working on a C# project and I'm very confused about the creation of a registry key.

I have a Wix Installer. And the and of the setup File, i'm calling a custom action to create sub key (I'v try with the wix feature but it didn't work).

My custom action is :

```
RegistryKey Nkey = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey valkey = Nkey.OpenSubKey(Manager.REGKEY, true); //=> REGKEY = "Software\\MyService"
if (valkey == null)
{
    valkey = Nkey.CreateSubKey(GestionCertificats.REGKEY);
}
valkey.Close();

Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyService");
```

After install, I can see the second key but no the first one. I'm not sure to right understand the operation of the keys. I'm working on a windows 7 64 bit, I'm compiling with "Any CPU" but my application seems to be in x86.

I've try to debug the action. value `valkey` is not null, but I didn't see the key with regedit. By forcing the `CreateSubKey` I still have no key.

I don't know what to do, I need help.

Comment: You need Admin rights to be able to write to LocalMachine. Are you running the installer with the correct privileges?

Comment: Yes, I have the windows asking for authorization. And I have another custom action used to write in an admin folder which is working.

Comment: I think you should use \\ and not just \ in the path?

Comment: I've retry on another PC, same result. `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyService` is correctly created but `Software\MyService` did not exist. But I saw that there is a registry in `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyService`. I compile my project in `Any CPU` but the install is done in "Programm file (x86". How to be sure if my application is 32 or 64 bits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess, because everything looks okay.

try closing the key returned.  The description of the dispose of a key it clears resources but doesn't say it flushes it.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyService");
key.Close();
```

Comment: It was a problem between base 32/64. I modified my key by : `RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);` and it works. You are the only one to answer, I take your answer ;-)